# sizeof error : incomplete type is not allowed

Tags: c, struct, malloc, sizeof

I have several C source and header files, with a `.h` file for each ADT.
One of them is called Tournament. When I try to malloc memory for tournament inside `tournament.h` no problem happens, but when I do it in a different c file it gives me the following error

"incomplete type is not allowed"

Here is the way tournament is defined in tournament.h

```
typedef struct tournament_t *Tournament;
```

ps: some people say it's a bad thing to typedef a struct but I have to do it since the instructors want it.

And this is how it is in `tournament.c` and I have no problems with it

```
struct tournament_t
{
 //fields
};
Tournament tournamentCreate()
{
  Tournament new=malloc(sizeof(*new));
    if(!new)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
//I don't get any error here
}
```

However, in a file called `chess.c`, this is what happens:

```
#include "tournament.h"
static Tournament copyTournament(Tournament tournament)
{
    if (!tournament) {
        return NULL;
    }
    Tournament copy = malloc(sizeof(*copy));//here I get the error
    if (!copy) 
    {
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

PS: the last function has to be `static` because again the instructor wants it to be.

If you need any more information to solve it, please tell me.

Comment: You need the definition of `struct tournament_t` in `tournament.h` so that it knows the size of the structure.

Comment: [Is it a good idea to typedef pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers)

Comment: that's intented, the idea behind ADT is that who uses them doesn't know how they work internally, so `tournament.c` is the only one where the struct definition is completed, and thus `malloc` can be used, the other files don't know how tournament struct works

Comment: @ozerodb If it's an ADT, then the functions that allocate them can only be in `tournament.c`.

Comment: correct, both the function to allocate and the function to free it

Comment: You can't do `sizeof(incomplete_type)` — you have to provide a function that knows how big the incomplete type is that handles the allocation (and another to deallocate the memory previously allocated).  Your ADT is incomplete because you don't have a complete set of support functions.  Code outside the implementation of the ADT can only use pointers to the ADT.

Comment: You have `Tournament copy = malloc(sizeof(*copy));` but you need to use `Tournament copy = tournamentCreate();`, which is already defined in the code, and later you'll need to call `tournamentDestroy(copy);` or its equivalent to delete the copy.

Comment: Note also that the rest of `copyTournament()` — the part that actually copies the data from the pre-existing `tournament` to the `copy` also needs inside knowledge of the structure.  The `copyTournament()` function needs to be in the file `tournament.c` and declared in `tournament.h` so it can be used by `chess.c`.

Comment: You say "When I try to malloc memory for tournament inside `tournament.h` no problem" — do you mean to reference `tournament.c`, or do you have an inline function definition in `tournament.h`, or what?  Usually, header files do not contain code that contains calls to `malloc()` — they contain type definitions, macros, and function declarations (and sometimes inline function definitions).  If they contain (non-inline or non-static) function definitions, they usually can't be used in more than one source file, which usually defeats the purpose of creating a header.  Headers share information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`typedef struct tournament_t *Tournament;` serves as a *forward declaration* of the struct. At this point in the header file, this contents of the struct is unknown to the compiler. It means that you need to write the struct definition elsewhere or the struct will rename unknown - an incomplete type.

You then place the struct definition in tournament.c. This means that the struct contents are now visible to the compiler inside that *translation unit*. Translation unit meaning that .c file and all the headers it includes.

This in turn means you are free to use the struct members inside tournament.c. But they will not be visible to chess.c. Because it is a different translation unit. All it can see is the forward declaration in the header, so it remains an incomplete type to chess.c.

If you had written the typedef as `typedef struct tournament_t Tournament;` without the pointer declaration, then chess.c wouldn't be able to even declare objects of this type, because it doesn't know how the struct is built. It can however declare pointers to an object of incomplete type - you can have a pointer without knowing the details of what it points at.

This is all likely by design, this method is known as "opaque type" and is how you design private encapsulation in C, to prevent the rest of the program from accessing members of a struct.

> some people say it's a bad thing to typedef a struct but I have to do it since the instructors want it.

Using typedef or not in combination with structs is 100% subjective coding style and there's no right or wrong there. However, using pointers together with typedef is often problematic, since it can trick the programmer into thinking they have a normal object and not a pointer. In your cases, it tricks you into believing you have access to the struct.

Since it's an incomplete type you can't declare an object of it outside tournament.c. Nor can you use `sizeof` on such an object. That's what the compiler error is about.

You should solve this by having tournament.h providing a function that copies objects, which in turn should be implemented in tournament.c. Note how "opaque type" is forcing you to do proper program design, instead of having non-related code in some other unrelated file doing things it shouldn't.